# Can't run python program in command prompt

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run the basic program in the command prompt. Code is basic: print("hello"), but when I try to input python ex_02.py in command prompt it always shows Nie mo. I use python 3.10.0. Picture of what is happening in command prompt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEkIJ.jpg.

Comment: hey please give [how do i ask good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read.

Comment: Are you claiming that `print('hello')` actually prints `Nie mo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the keyword 'py' instead of 'python'.
In your case you should write in your terminal

```
py ex_02.py
```